# Correct return type to pass by reference functions in C

Tags: c, function, return, pass-by-reference

I wrote a simple C program with a function that asks for two floating point numbers from the user passed by reference and the two numbers are printed to the screen using printf in main. My compiler is warning me about return at the end of the function "Expression result unused" and recommending to change it to this instead `return (void)(*a),*b;`  What is the correct way to return this function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

float getFloats(float *a, float *b);

int main()
{
    float num1,num2;
    
    getFloats(&num1,&num2);
    
    printf("%.2f, %.2f\n", num1, num2);
    
    return 0;
}

float getFloats(float *a, float *b)
{
    puts("Enter numbers:");
    scanf("%f", a);
    scanf("%f", b);
    
    return *a,*b;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to return anything. You're modifying the arguments because they're passed by reference.

Comment: You can't return multiple values in C. `return *a, *b;` is the same as `return *b;`

Comment: Where ".. they're passed by reference" is used loosely to denote modification of a shared object through an indirect pointer..

Comment: You don't need to return anything. the `scanf` already stores the values into the variables. So either change the function to have a `void` return type or return a single error code.

Comment: Excellent. that answers my question. thank you folks

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do

Answer (score 2):

changed it to void and it works. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getFloats(float *a, float *b);

int main()
{
    float num1,num2;
    
    getFloats(&num1,&num2);
    printf("%.2f and %.2f\n", num1, num2);
    
    return 0;
}

void getFloats(float *a, float *b)
{
    puts("Enter numbers:");
    scanf("%f", a);
    scanf("%f", b);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C you can't return more than one value. If you want to return more you need to wrap them into the struct.

```
struct TwoFloats
{
    float a,b;
};

struct TwoFloats getTwoFloats(void)
{
    struct TwoFloats tf;

    if(scanf("%f %f", &tf.a, &tf.b) != 2)
    {
        /* error handling  */
    }
    return tf;
}
```